# Using Markov chains for prediction

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, markov-process

i'm new to Markov theory and i'm trying to figure out how to solve the following question.

Given the following transitions matrix (A), What is the probability of 5 consecutive Z?
[image]

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: At least 5 or exactly 5? In 5 time steps or in some larger number of time-steps?

Comment: @Glen_b♦, exactly 5 and in 5 time steps

Comment: What is the state at the previous step?

Comment: @Glen_b♦ , the previous state is A(3,3)

Comment: A(3,3) is a transition probability, not a state!

Comment: @whuber♦, the previous state is Z

Comment: Does "five consecutive Z" include this one or not?  Would it perhaps include any Z's antecedent to the current state?

Comment: yes , "five consecutive Z" includes this one

Comment: So what you are really asking for is the chance that each of the next four transitions goes to the state "Z".  In the matrix you have shown us that the chance of each of those transitions is $0.7$.  Because this is a Markov chain those transitions are independent.  That's all you need to write down the answer immediately; the rest of the information in the question isn't relevant.

Comment: So what we're actually after is, "given we start in state $z$ at time 0, what's the chance that we then have exactly four $(z,z)$ transitions in a row"? (equivalently "...chance that $s_1,s_2,s_3$ and $s_4$ are also $z$")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Markov property tells you how to compute these probabilities:
$$
 P(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4, s_5|s_0)=P(s_5|s_4)P(s_4|s_3)P(s_3|s_2)P(s_2|s_1)P(s_1|s_0),
$$

you are asking for $P(s_{1:5}=ZZZZZ\,|\,s_0=Z)$, so that gives 
$$ 
  P(s_{1:5}=ZZZZZ\,|\,s_0=Z)=P(Z|Z)^5=(A_{ZZ})^5=0.7^5,
$$
so this is the probability of obtaining 5 consecutive $Z$'s right after seeing a $Z$.

Regarding your formula, I truly do not understand it.

Comment: ok so apparently from the comments in the OP it is 4, not 5 $Z$'s that we are looking at... Well, same reasoning applies

Comment: yes , it seems i mixed things up a bit

Comment: KF2: The original formula--now deleted--suggested you might be asking about *exactly* five Z's in a row.  One of your comments even hinted at that, where you indicated *five* time steps--even though only four steps are needed to achieve five Z's in a row.  The fifth step, then, would presumably be a non-Z.  If so, then the answer differs from the one given here.  At this point you have provided so much additional information in comments--all of it crucial--that you ought to edit the question to include all that information.

Comment: I agree with @whuber, let's make things clear for those to come...

Comment: But you can also think about this in terms of $P(5 Cons. Z's | s_0)$ which basically means that we do not necessarily start at $Z$, and I say this because a starting point has not been specified, in which case it would have to be $XZZZZZ + YZZZZZ + ZZZZZZ$. I only wanted to add this because the question itself is rather vague and all possibilities should be looked into. :)

Comment: Apparently, the comments in the OP suggest that they are 4 $Z$'s after starting on a $Z$. If you want 5 $Z$'s without prior assumptions, you need to start with the stationary state of the chain, which is the normalized eigenvector of the stochastic matrix with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: @AlexMonras Yeah but is that really necessary when dealing with the Markov Property?

Comment: I would say so. Computing the probabilities of $XZZZZZ+YZZZZZ+ZZZZZZ$ basically means computing the probability of 5 $Z$'s after any of the symbols, then take the average... but the average with respect to what? You need to weight them properly, and the natural way to do so is to assume the previous unknown symbol is distributed according to the stationary distribution of the process.

Answer (score 1):

If I suppose correctly and it is the probability of four consecutive (z,z) transitions you need, that's simply the result of four single (z,z) transitions; the probability follows immediately.

If you want to approach it formally, you could write the original problem as a conditional probability which you can use the Markov property and basic rules of conditional probability to break up into a product of individual transition probabilities.